# Website displays weird on Ipad/Iphone

Tags: ios, css, iphone, ipad

I have an odd situation over here. Our website displays fine on desktop and mac. Also on android devices (I'm using google nexus 7). But somehow, when viewing on an Ipad or Iphone, the website's css seems to b not as it should be. All divs, for example, are reacting weird and other stuff seems to get out of place for no reason that i can find. I tried several ios simulators (google aswell) and they all come out possitively and everything seems to be feen like currently it is on android devices. Only when trying on the devices themselve, it seems to get messed up.

Here is a link to the website: http://www.kiliwatch.be/ -> this is a directed/framed website
You can view the original source here: http://davion.be/kiliwatch/

Here is a screenshots on Ipad air: http://i.cubeupload.com/QCSYcE.png

Someone who has an idea why this occurs?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap for making it responsive ?
Have you added media query for these devices ?

Comment: how do you differ between your media queries / devices? it looks like it doesn't apply to it when using your ipad. (maybe something with your device detection)

Comment: Yes I'm using bootstrap for some elements in the website wich works fine on all devices accept Iphone and Ipad.

I'm using the standard media-queries: max-width 1200, 991,767,480,...